# Using wx.EVT_PAINT and wx.PaintDC

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

You use wx.EVT_PAINT and  wx.PaintDC to draw shapes, so that when window is resized (redrawn) shapes will not be lost. This works when the window is created. But, how will I preserve the shapes that I create after window is created?

Below, I present you a code, when the app first starts, a rectangle is drawn on the window. When user double clicks somewhere on the window, another rectangle is created. The initial rectangle is always preserved because it is bind to wx.EVT_PAINT event, so that it will be redrawn every time the window is redrawn.

But the second rectangle is not associated to the wx.EVT_PAINT, therefore it is lost when window is redrawn. How do I preserve the second rectangle as well?

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.on_left_double_click)


    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawRectangle(50, 60, 90, 40)


    def on_left_double_click(self, evt):
        x = evt.GetX()
        y = evt.GetY()
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("yellow"))
        dc.DrawRectangle(x, y, 90, 40)



class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test",style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,size=wx.Size(400, 300))
        self.main_panel = MyPanel(self)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Duplicate: See parallel discussion in [Google Groups: wxpython-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/kjcTqssVqW8).

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal solution to this except handling every drawing operation in a `wx.PaintDC`. You would do something along the lines of the following:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    # ...
    self.show_yellow_box = False
    self.box_pos = None

def OnPaint(self, evt):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.DrawRectangle(50, 60, 90, 40)
    if self.show_yellow_box:
        x, y = self.box_pos
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("yellow"))
        dc.DrawRectangle(x, y, 90, 40)

def on_left_double_click(self, evt):
    x = evt.GetX()
    y = evt.GetY()
    self.box_pos = (x, y)
    self.show_yellow_box = True
    self.Refresh() # important, to trigger EVT_PAINT on panel
```

If the operations in the paint event are more expensive, you probably will end up collecting the expensive drawing operations on the DC in a `wx.MemoryDC` and blit the bitmap content back onto the panel in the `MyPanel.OnPaint`.

There is a temporary DC (`wx.Overlay`/`wx.OverlayDC`), which is however only useful to apply temporary changes **between** paint events.

Comment: Could you please provide an example how to use wx.MemoryDC and blit?